# Como ordenar um ArrayList em ordem crescente pela data

Tags: java

Eu preciso ordenar um `ArrayList` em ordem crescente pela data. Pois eu vou adicionando valores fora de ordem nele. No meu `ArrayList` tem apenas dois campos em cada elemento: `data` e `valor`. Alguém sabe de algum método que eu posso usar?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione o que voce ja fez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar o método `sort` da classe Collections. O exemplo abaixo foi adaptado [desta resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5927408/5524514):

```
Collections.sort(suaLista, new Comparator<SeuObjeto>() {
  public int compare(SeuObjeto o1, SeuObjeto o2) {
      if (o1.getDate() == null || o2.getDate() == null)
        return 0;
      return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
  }
});
```

Comment: Consegui fazer o que eu queria usando esse esquema ali. Valeu!